# Copy constructors and passing classes around

Tags: c++, vector

Reverting this back to the original question.  Going to post the more detailed question as a new question.  Thanks everyone for the help and advice of avoiding the new.  Having trouble passing around instances of objects in this question.

```
class dogClass {
public:
    void setVariableA(std::vector<double> newNum) {
        variableA.push_back(newNum);
    }
    dogClass &dogClass::operator=(const dogClass &src) {
        variableA = src.variableA;
        return *this;
    }
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> variableA;
};

class animalClass {
public:
    void getDogOne(dogClass &dogOne) {
        dogOne = dogs[0];
    }
    void setDogOne(dogClass dogOne) {
        dogs.push_back(dogOne);
    }
private:
    std::vector<dogClass> dogs;
};


int main() {
    animalClass* iAnimalClass = new animalClass();
    dogClass* iDogClassOne= new dogClass();

    iAnimalClass->setDogOne(iDogClassOne);

    std::vector<double> newNum;
    newNum.push_back(12);
    newNum.push_back(15);

    iDogClassOne->setVariableA(newNum);

    dogClass iDogClassTwo;

    iAnimalClass->getDogOne(iDogClassTwo);

    //Why are iDogClassOne and iDogClassTwo not equal.
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: First thing is to stop creating objects with `new`. Second is to make your question much clearer.

Comment: Note that you don't pass **classes** around. You pass **objects** around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues.

1. you don't have a copy constructor for your dog class as you have indicated in your title. what you have done is overloaded the = operator.
2. you are trying to pass `iDogClassOne` as pointer to the `animalClass:: setDogOne()` but `animalclass::setDogOne` receives the arguments by value, not as reference or pointer.

   you can use the dereference operator`*iDogClassOne`. this pretty much telling the compiler you want to pass the object which the iDogClassOne is pointing at.

   ```
   dogClass* iDogClassOne = new dogClass();
   iAnimalClass->setDogOne(*iDogClassOne);
   ```

   or a better way of doing, you can completly remove the heap allocation

   ```
   dogClass dogobj;
   iAnimalClass->setDogOne(dogobj);
   ```
3. same problem as described in (2). but this time your `animalclass::getDogOne` receives the arguments by a reference.this again can be easly fixed by modifying the `getdogone` or/and by passing a pointer. i will leave this as it is. if you still need a help let me know in comments and will edit it further. but i encourage you to try to give it a go first.
4. you are missing semicolon (;) at the end of class declarations

Comment: Fixed the semicolons.... my classes are far more complex than this but I was trying to just write an example to explain my issues and missed the ;  Can you give me an example of how to fix #2 in your response?

Comment: tbf, it depends on how you want to fix this. if you want to keep the new operator which many people will scream nooo, you can pass it by dereferencing the pointer. `iAnimalClass->setDogOne(*iDogClassOne);` but i thnk the best method would be removing the new in the first place. instead of having `dogClass* iDogClassOne = new dogClass();` you can just have; `dogClass iDogClassOne;` since iDogClassOne no longer a pointer and just an object, it will work fine.

Comment: if you for some reason still want to go with allocating the object in the heap, then i highly suggest you to start using smart pointers instead.

Comment: I updated the initial post based on your comments.  Your comments were very helpful but I am still having issues.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: sure. but would you be a bit more specific of the current issues you having now?

Comment: if the issues you having now is vastly different then what the original question you asked , you may want to post another question.

Comment: I expect that iDogClassOne and iDogClassTwo would reference the same object, but they don't.  Also, when I add numbers into variableA by the function in the animal class, I cannot get those numbers to show up when I use the getDogOne function to get the instance of dogOne......  Basically I expect the console output to have tempDogOne, iDogClassOne, and iDogClassTwo to be equal and reference the same object.....  Does that make sense?

Comment: I reverted the original post back to the first question and posted another question per your advice.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: just to give some info on this further, you can not get the same dog object. first reason is that you storing dog into a vector. when you doing vector.pushback, vector does a copy of the object and pushes it into the vector. so they are different object